# Google Analytics API example JAVA

Tags: java

Google analytics posted on their blog about an example Java program to extract data and output to a CSV using the analytics api, im trying to compile this program to run it in eclipse but running into problems

http://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/DataOverTime/src/example/MainDemo.java

i have changed out the variables in here to my own:

```
// User configurations.
  private static final String USERNAME = "INSERT_YOUR_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "INSERT_YOUR_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD";
  private static final String TABLE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TABLE_ID";
```

i'm unsure on the next step, when i try to run the program i get this error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at MainDemo.main(main.java:51)
```

update:

ok, its says when using the google analytics API i need to reference some .jar files:

gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-analytics-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-analytics-2.0.jar
google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar
jsr305.jar

i put these in but its still not working i get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Results cannot be resolved to a type
    The method getData(DataQuery) from the type DataOverTime refers to the missing type Results
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer in this forum: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/groups/exportApiGroup.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-analytics-data-export-api%2FwpDmftjYFio%2Fdiscussion

Comment: -1: the link is broken. that's why it is recommended to write a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your directory structure correct?  It should look somewhat like the url of the example.
The file has to be './example/MainDemo.java' and compile it from '.'

Comment: ok i changed the project name to 'example' and the class to 'MainDemo.java' i saved then clicked run and i got the same error message, do i need to compile it first? im not sure how to do this in eclipse IDE sorry...

Comment: Ok, you're in eclipse.  What you need to do is create a new package called 'example' because at the top of MainDemo.java it says it's in that package.  Then in that package, add a file called MainDemo.java.  copy/paste the program into there.

Comment: hmm ok, i did this also. I think i may need to follow this tutorial first before i can do anything here http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/eclipse.html

Comment: So here's what to do to get this file run.  In the Package explorer, create a new project, call it whatever you want.  Tell it to add a source directory.  After is added, right click on the source directory and add a package called 'example', then right click on 'example' and tell it to create a class called MainDemo with public static void main stubbed out.  If that runs, you're in good shape, just clear that file's contents with your program.

Comment: i tried that but its not working i updated my description of the problem above