# How to get application data from Google Analytics API in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, analytics

I have a button on a web page when i click on button it should ask for credentials like gmail sign In. After that it will show related analytics record in response.
I have search on these below links but not found any help
[Google Analytics API example JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801331/google-analytics-api-example-java) 
 [Web Analytic API for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207846/web-analytic-api-for-java)

Comment: please edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your solution

Comment: i want some guideline how can i start this project as i have not found any exact solution to this issue i have tried these codes mentioned in above links but i am unable to do so

Comment: Welcome to stack we don't provide guides we provide assistance in fixing your solution.   Give it a try with the links you have now and ask another question if you have any problem remember to supply you code